# Why SVG render quality fail 'random' on IE?

Tags: internet-explorer, svg, rendering

I have a SVG chart, and it's painted ok on Chrome with all animations and all correct paths. But when runs on IE11, it try to animate and during the process it cuts the paths random. Every refresh, one different cut. When i click over the SVG element, appear all element well painted, but if i scroll the page, the SVG element is cut again.

[Sample random fails](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HoFya.png)

Comment: svg animations SMIL are not supported in IE at all.
Css animations are suported.

Comment: The problem is not the animation, the problem is the finish render. If i cancel the animation, the finish result is bad quality , with cuts in some places like in the photo.